# Completely regular spaces with common dense subspace.

Tags: general-topology

$(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(Y,\mathcal S)$ are completely regular topological spaces. $(X,\mathcal T)$ is compact and $X\cap Y$ is dense in both $X$ and $Y$.

Can we deduce $(Y,\mathcal S)$ is compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: Take $X=[0,1]$ with the usual topology and $Y=[0,1]\cap\Bbb Q$.